# как в дискрод боте в on_message бот пинговал пользователья и рандомно отвечал из списка

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Я делаю своего дискорд бота на pythonи я хочу чтобы когда человек писал какоето слово из списка бот его пинговал и рандомно отвечал из другого списка. Чтобы бот отвечал рандомно у меня сделать получилсь а чтобы он его пинговал и отвечал не получилось, код(списки показывать не буду):

```
@client.event
async def on_message( message ):

author = message.author

if msg in oi:
        await message.channel.send(f' { author.mention }  random.choiсe(ping)')
```

(на данный момент бот пингует меня и пишет random.choise(ping))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{random.choise(ping))} вместо random.choise(ping))`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).